# SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) for Oracle cannot find datatypes

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, migration

I am trying to migrate my Oracle db to SqlServer 2008 using SSMA. I defined some type mappings for columns. When I synchronize after converting schema it gives errors like: "Cannot find datatype datetime" or bit. These datatypes are valid SQL Server datatypes.

Why I am getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it's quite hard to provide more than that before you give more details... (the code being synchronized to SQL Server, first of all).

**Do you have case-sensitive collation on your SQL Server?** I believe SSMA may have problems in this case. Try synchronizing to case-insensitive DB.

Also you may try running generated SQL Server (translated) code in the Management Studio and then find the problem with generated SQL or DB setup from that point. Again, it's most likely possible to figure out the problem solely by looking at your generated SQL if it's indeed corrupted due to some bug in SSMA.